# Realm Swift: Database won't be updated after backup

Tags: ios, swift, database, orm, realm

I have the following workflow in my Swift app that ships with a realm database:

When the user installs the app:

1. I copy the realm file from the app bundle into the `Documents` folder as suggested here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#bundling-a-realm-with-an-app
2. The user changes data inside the database when using the app

When the user installs a new version of the app (updates it) and we changed some content (no schema changes) inside the shipped realm file:

1. I read the data from the realm file in the realm file in the `Documents` folder to back it up
2. I delete this realm file, all auxiliary files and every reference to `Realm` and `Results` instances
3. I copy the shipped realm file from the Bundle into the `Documents` folder
4. I write the backup data (read in step 1) back into the newly created realm file in the `Documents` folder.

The problem now is that the backup data written in step 4 is not persisted in the realm.

My question: Is there something wrong with my entire approach? Do I miss something?

I'd be happy to supply the code of any of the steps if you need more details (just don't want to post the entire code, it's quite long).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the realm was still cached even after I deleted it.

Turns out that I had to release all references to `Realm` and `Results` inside an `autoreleasepool` block. This fixed it.

Comment: I have the same scenario as yours, and I am doing the same steps as you have mentioned in the question. I used autoreleasepool too, but unfortunately, RLMRealm instance is not deallocated. I can see it there in a Thread.

Comment: How do you backup in 1st step? and how do you release references to objects?